# Center a sprintf message adding the name

Tags: c

I have code that works correctly if I use only the *Welcome* message, but when the `p->client_name` pointer is printed the message is not centered.

So my question is how can I center the message and the client name as if it were a single message. Why does it currently center only the message *welcome*

```
sprintf(message,"============================================================");
send_message(RED, message);
const char *mes = "Welcome";
sprintf(message, "[ %*s %s ]", (45 - strlen(message)) / 2 + ((strlen(message) % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0) + strlen(message), mes, p->client_name);
send_message(RED, message);
sprintf(message,"============================================================");
send_message(RED, message);
```

Example:

```
=============================================
              [ Welcome Carol ]               
=============================================
```

Comment: You want to make all text to be centred  be part of the calculations, won't you?

Comment: You need to replace the `%s` with `%-*s` and do another length calculation for the second part of the string.  I think I would create a function to do the job. It is not entirely trivial, though the maths isn’t incredibly hard either.

Comment: @alk that exactly what I want to do

Comment: But you don't. ;-) At least the code you show doesn't.

Comment: @jonathan-leffler But how can I calculate only the name pointer? I will not be able to use the value of the bars that is 45 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution to an interpretation of the original question

This code looks like it works.  The comments explain the calculation.  The test code shows how I go about testing such things.

```
/*
** Centre a pair of words in a given width without creating a single
** string to centre.
**
** Format will be "[ %*s %-*s ]"; what are the values required for the
** two lengths R1, R2 for a given width W and lengths L1, L2?
**
**      +----------------------------------------------------------+
**      [ @.........R1..........@ @..............R2..............@ ]
**      [        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY        ]
**      [   G1   |     L1       | |           L2          |   G2   ]
**      +----------------------------------------------------------+
**
** W = G1 + L1 + 1 + L2 + G2
**
** G1 = G2 or G1 + 1 = G2
** L1 + L2 + 1 <= W (return G1 = G2 = 1 if it is bigger)
**
** For the purposes of the calculation, the leading "[ " and trailing " ]"
** are not counted as part of W.
**
** Total Padding T = W - (L1 + L2 + 1)
** Hence: G1 = T / 2
**        G2 = T - G1
**        R1 = L1 + G1
**        R2 = L2 + G2
*/

static void centre_two_lengths(int w, int l1, int l2, int *r1, int *r2)
{
    int t = w - (l1 + l2 + 1);
    if (t <= 0)
    {
        *r1 = *r2 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int g1 = t / 2;
        int g2 = t - g1;
        *r1 = l1 + g1;
        *r2 = l2 + g2;
    }
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void test_width(int width)
{
    const char *data[] =
    {
        "A", "B",
        "AA", "B",
        "A", "BB",
        "A", "BBB",
        "A", "BBBB",
        "AAA", "B",
        "Hello", "World",
        "Middle of", "the road",
        "Welcome", "to Jurassic Park",
        "Bienvenue", "a Paris",
        "Twelve Place", "Twice - Over",
        "Eleven Here", "Thirteen Here",
        "Much much longer", "than this",
        "A", "Discourse on Inequality",
        "What sort of pedant am", "I",
        "What an essay", "busting all the limits",
    };
    int num_pairs = (sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])) / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_pairs; i++)
    {
        int r1;
        int r2;
        const char *s1 = data[2 * i + 0];
        const char *s2 = data[2 * i + 1];
        int l1 = strlen(s1);
        int l2 = strlen(s2);
        centre_two_lengths(width, l1, l2, &r1, &r2);
        printf("W = %2d, L1 = %2d, L2 = %2d, R1 = %2d, R2 = %2d   ", width, l1, l2, r1, r2);
        printf("[ %*s %-*s ]\n", r1, s1, r2, s2);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int width= 24; width < 30; width++)
        test_width(width);
    return(0);
}
```

Note that the code doesn't attempt to handle the cases where either `L1` or `L2` is zero.  It would be possible to do that for most cases, unless the non-zero length is too big.  It doesn't seem necessary, though.  The objective is to centre two (non-zero length) strings.  The calculation doesn't attempt to deal with leading or trailing spaces in the strings, either; it is simply assumed that there are no leading or trailing spaces.
It also assumes a single-byte code set; it won't centre UTF-8 properly if that has characters outside the ASCII range (and it won't handle control characters — back space, tab, newline, carriage return, etc — sensibly either).

Output:

```
W = 24, L1 =  1, L2 =  1, R1 = 11, R2 = 12   [           A B            ]
W = 24, L1 =  2, L2 =  1, R1 = 12, R2 = 11   [           AA B           ]
W = 24, L1 =  1, L2 =  2, R1 = 11, R2 = 12   [           A BB           ]
W = 24, L1 =  1, L2 =  3, R1 = 10, R2 = 13   [          A BBB           ]
W = 24, L1 =  1, L2 =  4, R1 = 10, R2 = 13   [          A BBBB          ]
W = 24, L1 =  3, L2 =  1, R1 = 12, R2 = 11   [          AAA B           ]
W = 24, L1 =  5, L2 =  5, R1 = 11, R2 = 12   [       Hello World        ]
W = 24, L1 =  9, L2 =  8, R1 = 12, R2 = 11   [    Middle of the road    ]
W = 24, L1 =  7, L2 = 16, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ Welcome to Jurassic Park ]
W = 24, L1 =  9, L2 =  7, R1 = 12, R2 = 11   [    Bienvenue a Paris     ]
W = 24, L1 = 12, L2 = 12, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ Twelve Place Twice - Over ]
W = 24, L1 = 11, L2 = 13, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ Eleven Here Thirteen Here ]
W = 24, L1 = 16, L2 =  9, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ Much much longer than this ]
W = 24, L1 =  1, L2 = 23, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ A Discourse on Inequality ]
W = 24, L1 = 22, L2 =  1, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ What sort of pedant am I ]
W = 24, L1 = 13, L2 = 22, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ What an essay busting all the limits ]
W = 25, L1 =  1, L2 =  1, R1 = 12, R2 = 12   [            A B            ]
W = 25, L1 =  2, L2 =  1, R1 = 12, R2 = 12   [           AA B            ]
W = 25, L1 =  1, L2 =  2, R1 = 11, R2 = 13   [           A BB            ]
W = 25, L1 =  1, L2 =  3, R1 = 11, R2 = 13   [           A BBB           ]
W = 25, L1 =  1, L2 =  4, R1 = 10, R2 = 14   [          A BBBB           ]
W = 25, L1 =  3, L2 =  1, R1 = 13, R2 = 11   [           AAA B           ]
W = 25, L1 =  5, L2 =  5, R1 = 12, R2 = 12   [        Hello World        ]
W = 25, L1 =  9, L2 =  8, R1 = 12, R2 = 12   [    Middle of the road     ]
W = 25, L1 =  7, L2 = 16, R1 =  7, R2 = 17   [ Welcome to Jurassic Park  ]
W = 25, L1 =  9, L2 =  7, R1 = 13, R2 = 11   [     Bienvenue a Paris     ]
W = 25, L1 = 12, L2 = 12, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ Twelve Place Twice - Over ]
W = 25, L1 = 11, L2 = 13, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ Eleven Here Thirteen Here ]
W = 25, L1 = 16, L2 =  9, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ Much much longer than this ]
W = 25, L1 =  1, L2 = 23, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ A Discourse on Inequality ]
W = 25, L1 = 22, L2 =  1, R1 = 22, R2 =  2   [ What sort of pedant am I  ]
W = 25, L1 = 13, L2 = 22, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ What an essay busting all the limits ]
W = 26, L1 =  1, L2 =  1, R1 = 12, R2 = 13   [            A B             ]
W = 26, L1 =  2, L2 =  1, R1 = 13, R2 = 12   [            AA B            ]
W = 26, L1 =  1, L2 =  2, R1 = 12, R2 = 13   [            A BB            ]
W = 26, L1 =  1, L2 =  3, R1 = 11, R2 = 14   [           A BBB            ]
W = 26, L1 =  1, L2 =  4, R1 = 11, R2 = 14   [           A BBBB           ]
W = 26, L1 =  3, L2 =  1, R1 = 13, R2 = 12   [           AAA B            ]
W = 26, L1 =  5, L2 =  5, R1 = 12, R2 = 13   [        Hello World         ]
W = 26, L1 =  9, L2 =  8, R1 = 13, R2 = 12   [     Middle of the road     ]
W = 26, L1 =  7, L2 = 16, R1 =  8, R2 = 17   [  Welcome to Jurassic Park  ]
W = 26, L1 =  9, L2 =  7, R1 = 13, R2 = 12   [     Bienvenue a Paris      ]
W = 26, L1 = 12, L2 = 12, R1 = 12, R2 = 13   [ Twelve Place Twice - Over  ]
W = 26, L1 = 11, L2 = 13, R1 = 11, R2 = 14   [ Eleven Here Thirteen Here  ]
W = 26, L1 = 16, L2 =  9, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ Much much longer than this ]
W = 26, L1 =  1, L2 = 23, R1 =  1, R2 = 24   [ A Discourse on Inequality  ]
W = 26, L1 = 22, L2 =  1, R1 = 23, R2 =  2   [  What sort of pedant am I  ]
W = 26, L1 = 13, L2 = 22, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ What an essay busting all the limits ]
W = 27, L1 =  1, L2 =  1, R1 = 13, R2 = 13   [             A B             ]
W = 27, L1 =  2, L2 =  1, R1 = 13, R2 = 13   [            AA B             ]
W = 27, L1 =  1, L2 =  2, R1 = 12, R2 = 14   [            A BB             ]
W = 27, L1 =  1, L2 =  3, R1 = 12, R2 = 14   [            A BBB            ]
W = 27, L1 =  1, L2 =  4, R1 = 11, R2 = 15   [           A BBBB            ]
W = 27, L1 =  3, L2 =  1, R1 = 14, R2 = 12   [            AAA B            ]
W = 27, L1 =  5, L2 =  5, R1 = 13, R2 = 13   [         Hello World         ]
W = 27, L1 =  9, L2 =  8, R1 = 13, R2 = 13   [     Middle of the road      ]
W = 27, L1 =  7, L2 = 16, R1 =  8, R2 = 18   [  Welcome to Jurassic Park   ]
W = 27, L1 =  9, L2 =  7, R1 = 14, R2 = 12   [      Bienvenue a Paris      ]
W = 27, L1 = 12, L2 = 12, R1 = 13, R2 = 13   [  Twelve Place Twice - Over  ]
W = 27, L1 = 11, L2 = 13, R1 = 12, R2 = 14   [  Eleven Here Thirteen Here  ]
W = 27, L1 = 16, L2 =  9, R1 = 16, R2 = 10   [ Much much longer than this  ]
W = 27, L1 =  1, L2 = 23, R1 =  2, R2 = 24   [  A Discourse on Inequality  ]
W = 27, L1 = 22, L2 =  1, R1 = 23, R2 =  3   [  What sort of pedant am I   ]
W = 27, L1 = 13, L2 = 22, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ What an essay busting all the limits ]
W = 28, L1 =  1, L2 =  1, R1 = 13, R2 = 14   [             A B              ]
W = 28, L1 =  2, L2 =  1, R1 = 14, R2 = 13   [             AA B             ]
W = 28, L1 =  1, L2 =  2, R1 = 13, R2 = 14   [             A BB             ]
W = 28, L1 =  1, L2 =  3, R1 = 12, R2 = 15   [            A BBB             ]
W = 28, L1 =  1, L2 =  4, R1 = 12, R2 = 15   [            A BBBB            ]
W = 28, L1 =  3, L2 =  1, R1 = 14, R2 = 13   [            AAA B             ]
W = 28, L1 =  5, L2 =  5, R1 = 13, R2 = 14   [         Hello World          ]
W = 28, L1 =  9, L2 =  8, R1 = 14, R2 = 13   [      Middle of the road      ]
W = 28, L1 =  7, L2 = 16, R1 =  9, R2 = 18   [   Welcome to Jurassic Park   ]
W = 28, L1 =  9, L2 =  7, R1 = 14, R2 = 13   [      Bienvenue a Paris       ]
W = 28, L1 = 12, L2 = 12, R1 = 13, R2 = 14   [  Twelve Place Twice - Over   ]
W = 28, L1 = 11, L2 = 13, R1 = 12, R2 = 15   [  Eleven Here Thirteen Here   ]
W = 28, L1 = 16, L2 =  9, R1 = 17, R2 = 10   [  Much much longer than this  ]
W = 28, L1 =  1, L2 = 23, R1 =  2, R2 = 25   [  A Discourse on Inequality   ]
W = 28, L1 = 22, L2 =  1, R1 = 24, R2 =  3   [   What sort of pedant am I   ]
W = 28, L1 = 13, L2 = 22, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ What an essay busting all the limits ]
W = 29, L1 =  1, L2 =  1, R1 = 14, R2 = 14   [              A B              ]
W = 29, L1 =  2, L2 =  1, R1 = 14, R2 = 14   [             AA B              ]
W = 29, L1 =  1, L2 =  2, R1 = 13, R2 = 15   [             A BB              ]
W = 29, L1 =  1, L2 =  3, R1 = 13, R2 = 15   [             A BBB             ]
W = 29, L1 =  1, L2 =  4, R1 = 12, R2 = 16   [            A BBBB             ]
W = 29, L1 =  3, L2 =  1, R1 = 15, R2 = 13   [             AAA B             ]
W = 29, L1 =  5, L2 =  5, R1 = 14, R2 = 14   [          Hello World          ]
W = 29, L1 =  9, L2 =  8, R1 = 14, R2 = 14   [      Middle of the road       ]
W = 29, L1 =  7, L2 = 16, R1 =  9, R2 = 19   [   Welcome to Jurassic Park    ]
W = 29, L1 =  9, L2 =  7, R1 = 15, R2 = 13   [       Bienvenue a Paris       ]
W = 29, L1 = 12, L2 = 12, R1 = 14, R2 = 14   [   Twelve Place Twice - Over   ]
W = 29, L1 = 11, L2 = 13, R1 = 13, R2 = 15   [   Eleven Here Thirteen Here   ]
W = 29, L1 = 16, L2 =  9, R1 = 17, R2 = 11   [  Much much longer than this   ]
W = 29, L1 =  1, L2 = 23, R1 =  3, R2 = 25   [   A Discourse on Inequality   ]
W = 29, L1 = 22, L2 =  1, R1 = 24, R2 =  4   [   What sort of pedant am I    ]
W = 29, L1 = 13, L2 = 22, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   [ What an essay busting all the limits ]
```

---

#### But I didn't mean that — I meant something else

This code seems to meet the revised requirement.

```
/*
** Given two words W1,W2, enclose them in square brackets "[ W1 W2]"
** Centre a pair of words in a given width without creating a single
** string to centre.
**
** Format will be "%*s[ %s %s ]%*s"; what are the values required for
** R1, R2 given the two lengths L1, L2 and width W?
**
**      +----------------------------------------------------------+
**      |                                                          |
**      |      [ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY ]      |
**      |  R1  | |     L1       | |           L2          | |  R2  |
**      +----------------------------------------------------------+
**
** W = R1 + L1 + 5 + L2 + R2
**
** for centred output, either R1 = R2 or R1 + 1 = R2
** L1 + L2 + 5 <= W (return R1 = R2 = 0 if it is bigger)
**
** Total Padding T = W - (L1 + L2 + 5)
** Hence: R1 = T / 2
**        R2 = T - R1
*/

static void centre_two_lengths(int w, int l1, int l2, int *r1, int *r2)
{
    int t = w - (l1 + l2 + 5);
    if (t <= 0)
    {
        *r1 = *r2 = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        *r1 = t / 2;
        *r2 = t - *r1;
    }
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void test_width(int width)
{
    const char *data[] =
    {
        "A", "B",
        "AA", "B",
        "A", "BB",
        "A", "BBB",
        "A", "BBBB",
        "AAA", "B",
        "Hello", "World",
        "Middle of", "the road",
        "Welcome", "to Jurassic Park",
        "Bienvenue", "a Paris",
        "Twelve Place", "Twice - Over",
        "Eleven Here", "Thirteen Here",
        "Much much longer", "than this",
        "A", "Discourse on Inequality",
        "What sort of pedant am", "I",
        "What an essay", "busting all the limits",
    };
    int num_pairs = (sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])) / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_pairs; i++)
    {
        int r1;
        int r2;
        const char *s1 = data[2 * i + 0];
        const char *s2 = data[2 * i + 1];
        int l1 = strlen(s1);
        int l2 = strlen(s2);
        centre_two_lengths(width, l1, l2, &r1, &r2);
        printf("W = %2d, L1 = %2d, L2 = %2d, R1 = %2d, R2 = %2d   ", width, l1, l2, r1, r2);
        printf("|%*s[ %s %s ]%*s|\n", r1, "", s1, s2, r2, "");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int width= 28; width < 34; width++)
        test_width(width);
    return(0);
}
```

If you don't want the trailing spaces, you can simplify the function — it could simply return the value needed for the leading spaces, and you'd drop the trailing `%*s` from the format string and the `r2` and subsequent `""`.  The vertical bars are there simply so you can see whether the data is centred properly (and the trailing bar needs the trailing spaces to make any sense).

Output:

```
W = 28, L1 =  1, L2 =  1, R1 = 10, R2 = 11   |          [ A B ]           |
W = 28, L1 =  2, L2 =  1, R1 = 10, R2 = 10   |          [ AA B ]          |
W = 28, L1 =  1, L2 =  2, R1 = 10, R2 = 10   |          [ A BB ]          |
W = 28, L1 =  1, L2 =  3, R1 =  9, R2 = 10   |         [ A BBB ]          |
W = 28, L1 =  1, L2 =  4, R1 =  9, R2 =  9   |         [ A BBBB ]         |
W = 28, L1 =  3, L2 =  1, R1 =  9, R2 = 10   |         [ AAA B ]          |
W = 28, L1 =  5, L2 =  5, R1 =  6, R2 =  7   |      [ Hello World ]       |
W = 28, L1 =  9, L2 =  8, R1 =  3, R2 =  3   |   [ Middle of the road ]   |
W = 28, L1 =  7, L2 = 16, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ Welcome to Jurassic Park ]|
W = 28, L1 =  9, L2 =  7, R1 =  3, R2 =  4   |   [ Bienvenue a Paris ]    |
W = 28, L1 = 12, L2 = 12, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ Twelve Place Twice - Over ]|
W = 28, L1 = 11, L2 = 13, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ Eleven Here Thirteen Here ]|
W = 28, L1 = 16, L2 =  9, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ Much much longer than this ]|
W = 28, L1 =  1, L2 = 23, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ A Discourse on Inequality ]|
W = 28, L1 = 22, L2 =  1, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ What sort of pedant am I ]|
W = 28, L1 = 13, L2 = 22, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ What an essay busting all the limits ]|
W = 29, L1 =  1, L2 =  1, R1 = 11, R2 = 11   |           [ A B ]           |
W = 29, L1 =  2, L2 =  1, R1 = 10, R2 = 11   |          [ AA B ]           |
W = 29, L1 =  1, L2 =  2, R1 = 10, R2 = 11   |          [ A BB ]           |
W = 29, L1 =  1, L2 =  3, R1 = 10, R2 = 10   |          [ A BBB ]          |
W = 29, L1 =  1, L2 =  4, R1 =  9, R2 = 10   |         [ A BBBB ]          |
W = 29, L1 =  3, L2 =  1, R1 = 10, R2 = 10   |          [ AAA B ]          |
W = 29, L1 =  5, L2 =  5, R1 =  7, R2 =  7   |       [ Hello World ]       |
W = 29, L1 =  9, L2 =  8, R1 =  3, R2 =  4   |   [ Middle of the road ]    |
W = 29, L1 =  7, L2 = 16, R1 =  0, R2 =  1   |[ Welcome to Jurassic Park ] |
W = 29, L1 =  9, L2 =  7, R1 =  4, R2 =  4   |    [ Bienvenue a Paris ]    |
W = 29, L1 = 12, L2 = 12, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ Twelve Place Twice - Over ]|
W = 29, L1 = 11, L2 = 13, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ Eleven Here Thirteen Here ]|
W = 29, L1 = 16, L2 =  9, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ Much much longer than this ]|
W = 29, L1 =  1, L2 = 23, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ A Discourse on Inequality ]|
W = 29, L1 = 22, L2 =  1, R1 =  0, R2 =  1   |[ What sort of pedant am I ] |
W = 29, L1 = 13, L2 = 22, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ What an essay busting all the limits ]|
W = 30, L1 =  1, L2 =  1, R1 = 11, R2 = 12   |           [ A B ]            |
W = 30, L1 =  2, L2 =  1, R1 = 11, R2 = 11   |           [ AA B ]           |
W = 30, L1 =  1, L2 =  2, R1 = 11, R2 = 11   |           [ A BB ]           |
W = 30, L1 =  1, L2 =  3, R1 = 10, R2 = 11   |          [ A BBB ]           |
W = 30, L1 =  1, L2 =  4, R1 = 10, R2 = 10   |          [ A BBBB ]          |
W = 30, L1 =  3, L2 =  1, R1 = 10, R2 = 11   |          [ AAA B ]           |
W = 30, L1 =  5, L2 =  5, R1 =  7, R2 =  8   |       [ Hello World ]        |
W = 30, L1 =  9, L2 =  8, R1 =  4, R2 =  4   |    [ Middle of the road ]    |
W = 30, L1 =  7, L2 = 16, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   | [ Welcome to Jurassic Park ] |
W = 30, L1 =  9, L2 =  7, R1 =  4, R2 =  5   |    [ Bienvenue a Paris ]     |
W = 30, L1 = 12, L2 = 12, R1 =  0, R2 =  1   |[ Twelve Place Twice - Over ] |
W = 30, L1 = 11, L2 = 13, R1 =  0, R2 =  1   |[ Eleven Here Thirteen Here ] |
W = 30, L1 = 16, L2 =  9, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ Much much longer than this ]|
W = 30, L1 =  1, L2 = 23, R1 =  0, R2 =  1   |[ A Discourse on Inequality ] |
W = 30, L1 = 22, L2 =  1, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   | [ What sort of pedant am I ] |
W = 30, L1 = 13, L2 = 22, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ What an essay busting all the limits ]|
W = 31, L1 =  1, L2 =  1, R1 = 12, R2 = 12   |            [ A B ]            |
W = 31, L1 =  2, L2 =  1, R1 = 11, R2 = 12   |           [ AA B ]            |
W = 31, L1 =  1, L2 =  2, R1 = 11, R2 = 12   |           [ A BB ]            |
W = 31, L1 =  1, L2 =  3, R1 = 11, R2 = 11   |           [ A BBB ]           |
W = 31, L1 =  1, L2 =  4, R1 = 10, R2 = 11   |          [ A BBBB ]           |
W = 31, L1 =  3, L2 =  1, R1 = 11, R2 = 11   |           [ AAA B ]           |
W = 31, L1 =  5, L2 =  5, R1 =  8, R2 =  8   |        [ Hello World ]        |
W = 31, L1 =  9, L2 =  8, R1 =  4, R2 =  5   |    [ Middle of the road ]     |
W = 31, L1 =  7, L2 = 16, R1 =  1, R2 =  2   | [ Welcome to Jurassic Park ]  |
W = 31, L1 =  9, L2 =  7, R1 =  5, R2 =  5   |     [ Bienvenue a Paris ]     |
W = 31, L1 = 12, L2 = 12, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   | [ Twelve Place Twice - Over ] |
W = 31, L1 = 11, L2 = 13, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   | [ Eleven Here Thirteen Here ] |
W = 31, L1 = 16, L2 =  9, R1 =  0, R2 =  1   |[ Much much longer than this ] |
W = 31, L1 =  1, L2 = 23, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   | [ A Discourse on Inequality ] |
W = 31, L1 = 22, L2 =  1, R1 =  1, R2 =  2   | [ What sort of pedant am I ]  |
W = 31, L1 = 13, L2 = 22, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ What an essay busting all the limits ]|
W = 32, L1 =  1, L2 =  1, R1 = 12, R2 = 13   |            [ A B ]             |
W = 32, L1 =  2, L2 =  1, R1 = 12, R2 = 12   |            [ AA B ]            |
W = 32, L1 =  1, L2 =  2, R1 = 12, R2 = 12   |            [ A BB ]            |
W = 32, L1 =  1, L2 =  3, R1 = 11, R2 = 12   |           [ A BBB ]            |
W = 32, L1 =  1, L2 =  4, R1 = 11, R2 = 11   |           [ A BBBB ]           |
W = 32, L1 =  3, L2 =  1, R1 = 11, R2 = 12   |           [ AAA B ]            |
W = 32, L1 =  5, L2 =  5, R1 =  8, R2 =  9   |        [ Hello World ]         |
W = 32, L1 =  9, L2 =  8, R1 =  5, R2 =  5   |     [ Middle of the road ]     |
W = 32, L1 =  7, L2 = 16, R1 =  2, R2 =  2   |  [ Welcome to Jurassic Park ]  |
W = 32, L1 =  9, L2 =  7, R1 =  5, R2 =  6   |     [ Bienvenue a Paris ]      |
W = 32, L1 = 12, L2 = 12, R1 =  1, R2 =  2   | [ Twelve Place Twice - Over ]  |
W = 32, L1 = 11, L2 = 13, R1 =  1, R2 =  2   | [ Eleven Here Thirteen Here ]  |
W = 32, L1 = 16, L2 =  9, R1 =  1, R2 =  1   | [ Much much longer than this ] |
W = 32, L1 =  1, L2 = 23, R1 =  1, R2 =  2   | [ A Discourse on Inequality ]  |
W = 32, L1 = 22, L2 =  1, R1 =  2, R2 =  2   |  [ What sort of pedant am I ]  |
W = 32, L1 = 13, L2 = 22, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ What an essay busting all the limits ]|
W = 33, L1 =  1, L2 =  1, R1 = 13, R2 = 13   |             [ A B ]             |
W = 33, L1 =  2, L2 =  1, R1 = 12, R2 = 13   |            [ AA B ]             |
W = 33, L1 =  1, L2 =  2, R1 = 12, R2 = 13   |            [ A BB ]             |
W = 33, L1 =  1, L2 =  3, R1 = 12, R2 = 12   |            [ A BBB ]            |
W = 33, L1 =  1, L2 =  4, R1 = 11, R2 = 12   |           [ A BBBB ]            |
W = 33, L1 =  3, L2 =  1, R1 = 12, R2 = 12   |            [ AAA B ]            |
W = 33, L1 =  5, L2 =  5, R1 =  9, R2 =  9   |         [ Hello World ]         |
W = 33, L1 =  9, L2 =  8, R1 =  5, R2 =  6   |     [ Middle of the road ]      |
W = 33, L1 =  7, L2 = 16, R1 =  2, R2 =  3   |  [ Welcome to Jurassic Park ]   |
W = 33, L1 =  9, L2 =  7, R1 =  6, R2 =  6   |      [ Bienvenue a Paris ]      |
W = 33, L1 = 12, L2 = 12, R1 =  2, R2 =  2   |  [ Twelve Place Twice - Over ]  |
W = 33, L1 = 11, L2 = 13, R1 =  2, R2 =  2   |  [ Eleven Here Thirteen Here ]  |
W = 33, L1 = 16, L2 =  9, R1 =  1, R2 =  2   | [ Much much longer than this ]  |
W = 33, L1 =  1, L2 = 23, R1 =  2, R2 =  2   |  [ A Discourse on Inequality ]  |
W = 33, L1 = 22, L2 =  1, R1 =  2, R2 =  3   |  [ What sort of pedant am I ]   |
W = 33, L1 = 13, L2 = 22, R1 =  0, R2 =  0   |[ What an essay busting all the limits ]|
```

Comment: your code works, however it centers inside the brackets I'm trying a way to center in the middle of the prompt, example in the topic.

Comment: This is why you should show what you want clearly from the start.  Your original code without the example output was so confusing as to be very difficult to interpret what you want.  In particular, the `*` in `%*s` seems completely superfluous for the output you have now decided you want.  I'll work out a solution shortly — but you *must* make sure that your desired output is clear in future questions.  Do you need trailing blanks to make the line up to the given width, or do you not need those?

Comment: yes need the spaces to center the message, this value _45_ I used the amount of `=` to calculate

Comment: @Jhonathan Leffer Thank you very much.